# LINQ adding format to date column in where clause

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
select * 
from   qmsCallAudit 
where CAST(FLOOR(CAST(callauditdt AS float)) AS DATETIME) 
    between '2015-07-16 00:00:00' and '2015-07-16 00:00:00'
```

above query return records in sql query

from linq its not not working, below is application code

```
        var query  = (
                    from qd in db.qmsCallAuditDetails
                    from qm in db.qmsCallAudits
                    where qm.callaudit_id == qd.callaudit_id &&
                    qm.active == true
                    && qm.process_id == processid
                    && fdt >= qm.callauditdt
                    && tdt <= qm.callauditdt
                    select qd
                  ).AsQueryable();

        string semp = frm["employee_id"];
        if (semp.Length > 0)
        {
            int empid = Convert.ToInt32(frm["employee_id"]);
            query = query.Where(q => q.qmsCallAudit.employee_id==empid);
        }
```

below sql profile code for above linq query

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[callauditdetail_id] AS [callauditdetail_id], 
    [Extent1].[callaudit_id] AS [callaudit_id], 
    [Extent1].[subparameter_id] AS [subparameter_id], 
    [Extent1].[subparameterdisp_id] AS [subparameterdisp_id], 
    [Extent1].[score] AS [score], 
    [Extent1].[weightage] AS [weightage], 
    [Extent1].[fatal] AS [fatal], 
    [Extent1].[add_to_weightage] AS [add_to_weightage], 
    [Extent1].[auditstatus] AS [auditstatus], 
    [Extent1].[auditscore] AS [auditscore], 
    [Extent1].[auditweightage] AS [auditweightage], 
    [Extent1].[auditremark] AS [auditremark], 
    [Extent1].[createdon] AS [createdon], 
    [Extent1].[createdby] AS [createdby], 
    [Extent1].[modifiedon] AS [modifiedon], 
    [Extent1].[modifiedby] AS [modifiedby], 
    [Extent1].[active] AS [active]
    FROM  [dbo].[qmsCallAuditDetail] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[qmsCallAudit] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent2].[callaudit_id] = [Extent1].[callaudit_id]
    WHERE (1 = [Extent2].[active]) AND ([Extent2].[process_id] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__1 >= [Extent2].CAST(FLOOR(CAST(callauditdt AS float)))[callauditdt]) AND (@p__linq__2 <= [Extent2].[callauditdt])',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0=2,@p__linq__1='2015-07-16 00:00:00',@p__linq__2='2015-07-16 00:00:00'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Whats your error?  Are your ftd and tdt already dateTime objects?